# Changing Values of Lists In Loop With Fish Shell Script

Tags: shell, scripting, fish

I am trying to iterate over a fish shell list and change the values of the elements saving those new values into that list.

The original list is populated like this:

```
set -l dockApplications (ls $HOME/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/)
```

This works and produces a list like this:

```
emacsclient.dockitem firefox.dockitem monodevelop.dockitem Thunar.dockitem
```

Now I want to iterate over it and change the string "dockitem" to "desktop".

I have tried a for loop but I do not appear to be using it correctly:

```
for application in $dockApplications
     echo $application
     set application (string replace 'dockitem' 'desktop' $application )
     echo $application
     echo "==========="
end
```

This echos the before and after the string operation and I produce the correct string. but when I do something like `echo $dockApplications` after the for loop. I get the list of strings with the "dockitem" extension.

I have also tried setting the `$dockApplications` variable differently like:

```
set -l dockApplications (string replace 'dockitem' 'desktop' (ls $HOME/.config/plank/$dockdir/launchers/))
```

But that seems to return the same list of strings with the "dockitem" extension.

I think I am fundamentally misunderstanding either how variables are assigned or how the scope of them is handled here.

I have never fully wrapped my head around shell scripting. I can read it and get what is going on but when it comes to implementing it I hit a few road blocks when I try to achieve something in a way that I would in a different language. But I realize the power of shell scripting and would like to get better at it. So any pointers on how to do this in a fish shell idiomatic way are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What helped me become proficient in shell languages is to have the manual at my elbow, always.

Comment: The `application` var not get a reference to the original value, it gets a copy of the value. So you're modifying a copy of the original value. In addition to the solutions provided by Glenn I would recommend not modifying the original array in place. Make a new array as you iterate over the original.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would iterate over the **indices** of the list so you can update in place:

```
set apps (printf "%s\n" ./launchers/*.dockitem)
for i in (seq (count $apps))
    set apps[$i] (string replace "dockitem" "desktop" $apps[$i])
end
printf "%s\n" $apps
```

This also works without a loop:

```
set apps (string replace dockitem desktop (printf "%s\n" ./launchers/*.dockitem))
printf "%s\n" $apps
```

If I recall, fish splits the output of a command substitution on newlines when saving to an array

Comment: Thanks this works! I also realized that one of my solutions works too but I misspelled 'dock'.

Comment: There is no need for the `printf`, and it even adds a (mostly theoretical) bug if filenames contain newlines. Just `set apps ./launchers/*.dockitem` directly.

Comment: If you truly aren't concerned about newlines, you could also call `set apps (string replace "dockitem" "desktop" -- ./launchers/*.dockitem)` directly and skip the loop entirely.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the most elegant solution, but here is a pure fish way of doing this using the venerable `string` function.

```
set mystring "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"
set mywords (string split " " $mystring)
for i in (seq (count $mywords))
    set mywords[$i] (string upper (string sub -s 1 -l 1 $mywords[$i]))(string sub -s 2 $mywords[$i])
end
echo $mywords
```